# Fixing coordinates of Jquery gmap

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

Is it possible to have a gmap that is a fixed view?  In other words, there is no hand cursor that lets the user change the location of the map?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#map").gMap({ controls: false,
                  scrollwheel: false,
                      draggable: false,
                  markers: [{ latitude: 40.727047,
                              longitude: 1006.8,
                              icon: { image: "img/pin.png",
                                      iconsize: [32, 47],
                                      iconanchor: [32,47],
                                      infowindowanchor: [12, 0] } }
                            ],
                  icon: { image: "img/pin.png", 
                          iconsize: [26, 46],
                          iconanchor: [12, 46],
                          infowindowanchor: [12, 0] },
                  latitude: 44.47698,
                  longitude: 1006.8,
                  zoom: 15, });
```

});

Comment: The controls option should be an array. The gmap documentation says "A simple array of string values representing the function names (without "()") to add controls. Please refer to the Google Maps API for possible values. If empty the default map controls will be applied." Gmap is built on the Google maps V2 API, so make sure you consult the V2 documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well use a static map if your not using any of the controls:

[static map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

otherwise you can customize any of the controls to be added with:

[Gcontrol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GControl)